# Can't create/save any new files in VSCode on Mac Catalina and keep getting a read-only file system error

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, readonly, macos-catalina

Failed to save 'Untitled-1': Unable to write file (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/Untitled-1.html')

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you’re running into is you’re trying to create files in the root (/) directory. One of the changes Apple made when they released Catalina was that the root directory is Read-Only, which explains the error you’re seeing.

The reason for this is enhanced security and you can read more about it [here](https://www.macobserver.com/analysis/macos-catalina-protects-os-read-only-volume/). I would recommend you change to your home (~/) directory and make all of your files in there. This should take care of all file system errors you’re currently experiencing.